# In PHP I am getting an error while trying to use INSERT command

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

This is my php code trying to insert the data from form into the database but I am getting error in Insert line.

```
if(isset($_POST['bankname']))
{

    $bname=$_POST['bankname'];

    $amt=$_POST['amount'];

    $cond=$_POST['cond'];

    $medi=$_POST['mediate'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO dr (bankname, amount, cond, mediate)     VALUES('$bname','$amt','$cond', '$medi')";

    if ($conn->$sql=== TRUE)
    {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    echo "<br/>Form Submitted succesfully";
}
```

I am getting error as below

> Error: `INSERT INTO dr (bankname, amount, cond, mediate) VALUES ('', '', '----choose----', '')`

Comment: Please post your code and the exact error message you are getting properly.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: `$conn->$sql` is non-sense. Actually whole condition doesn't make any sense: `if ($conn->$sql === TRUE)`. You even didn't execute the query, so I don't understand, what and why you're trying to check. And neither you I guess. Do you understand what is your code supposed to do?

Comment: Can you please tell me what I have to do to get insert the data into the database

Comment: From the error msgs there is no value to insert and also are your tables realy exists? and you put `joomla` tag, why not using joomla database api?

Answer (score 1):

```
string mysql_real_escape_string(string unescaped_string,
                                resource link_identifier= =NULL);
```

Escapes special characters in the unescaped_string, taking into account the current character set of the connection so that it is safe to place it in a mysql_query. If binary data is to be inserted, this function must be used.
Parameters

**unescaped_string**
The string that is to be escaped.

**link_identifier**
The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect had been called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

**Return Values**

Returns the escaped string, or FALSE on error.

**Errors/Exceptions**

Executing this function without a MySQL connection present will also emit E_WARNING level PHP errors. Only execute this function with a valid MySQL connection present.

Examples

```
<?php
// Connect
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    OR die(mysql_error());

// Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
?>
```

refer link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-function.mysql-real-escape-string.html

Comment: But Abhijit brother I am not getting any other errors but the error is showing INSERT line

Comment: you used '----choose----' to insert and --is sql comment so use mysql_real_escape_string() function to avoid such error

Comment: I simply tried submitting without any inputs

Comment: Error: INSERT INTO dr (bankname, amount, cond, mediate) VALUES('swiss bank','120000','write off', 'Yes')

Form Submitted succesfully

Comment: the above thing is the error i am getting

Answer (score 1):

Working Fine Try This

**See Live Demo** [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/331ef/3)

**See Image** 
[image]

Comment: sumit I have done storing the data into into the database but this time i am getting the error